# How to Display Anchor Text with JavaScript Even if it is Removed or Changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

Javascript Expert,

Below is my html structure that i used in all my templates. Now i want if someone remove or changed the anchor text **"Pro Blogger Tricks"** then it should display the same anchor text even if it as changed or removed.

```
<div id='copyright'>
    <div id='container'>
        <p> Designed by: <a href='http://www.probloggertricks.com'>**Pro Blogger Tricks**</a> 
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Case 1:** For example someone changed the **"Pro Blogger Tricks"** to **"Awesome Mag"** then it should display the same "Pro Blogger Tricks" not the "Awesome Mag" anchor.

*Case 1: Example:*

```
<div id='copyright'>
    <div id='container'>
        <p> Designed by: <a href='http://www.probloggertricks.com'>Awesome Mag</a> 
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Case 2: If someone removed the anchor text "Pro Blogger Tricks" then even it should display the same "Pro Blogger Tricks" even if it is removed.

*Case 2: Example:*

```
<div id='copyright'>
    <div id='container'>
        <p> Designed by: <a href='http://www.probloggertricks.com'></a> 
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Attention:** Please use the condition in such way, that if url is http://www.probloggertricks.com then its anchor should be "**Pro Blogger Tricks**" even if it either change or removed, it should display the desire one we set in javascript.

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks to ask that, simple i created templates and i put my html structure at the bottom, often users download my template and changed only the Anchor text, for url i used already javascript they cannot remove or changed my url however they changed the anchor text. so thats why i want if they changed or removed it should display the desired anchor text we set in jasvascript. i hope you got it. thanks.

Comment: You cannot avoid anyone to remove/change credits. Really you cannot. You could integrate some verification logic BUT we are talking about code rendered client side. You just cannot avoid it. There are many, many ways someone would be able to still remove credits. OR you display your template in cross domain iframe but that's for sure not a solution...

Comment: I set all the rest thing, no one will removed or changed my credit..that i know very well, but just as favor on me, if you can create this script for me, then i will share the full code, that no one will be easily removed the credit link, so please share the code what i want here. and i know it is simple.

Comment: As @A.Wolff says... *It is very easy to remove the credit link, no matter what you change*. People will just remove/change your code too. Just forget it and move on. The threat of copyright infringement is the only protection you really have (and that is hard to enforce). :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie i created all the script for this work, please just share the code with me,  if anchor text "pro blogger tricks" changed or removed display the same "pro blogger tricks" anchor texts..thats simple i want..please do it if you can.

Comment: Just use an interval timer and scan all links every few seconds. If the link HREF matches your URL, set the text using `.htm()`. It's trivial but a complete waste of time (as everyone keeps indicating) :) Added code below. Took 60 seconds to write.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to check regularly, as other plugins may change links on the fly, you can do this:

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/v7x0yt02/3/

```
$(function() {
  var f = function() {
    $('a[href="http://www.probloggertricks.com"]').html("Complete waste of time!");
  }
  f();
  setInterval(f, 2000);
});
```

[image]

Comment: the code is not working, it show the same anchor we add in html..as you set the "complete wast of time" it should be displayed but its not...check the screenshot http://prntscr.com/9mv48x  or do check yourself in that jsfiddle

Comment: Works fine on Chrome and just tested it on my phone. Screenshot to follow. The code is trivial. No idea what you are doing different.

Comment: please remove the time interval condition for me...so it display at once..no delay should be there.

Comment: @RajeshSurry: Are you seriously saying you can't change those few lines of code to run initially as well as inside the timer? Please have a try first... This is not `CodeItForMe.com` :)

Comment: Thanks i removed my self, it now worked, <script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href="http://www.example.com"]').html("Complete waste of time!");
})
//]]>
</script>

Comment: can you also add the title tag ? means so we also set title for anchor text...when mouse over on anchor and it display the title as we set in html. thanks.